# How to Install SSL/HTTPS on phpMyAdmin on Bitnami (GCP)

Tags: wordpress, ssl, google-cloud-platform, phpmyadmin, bitnami

I installed WordPress on GCP using Bitnami Certified by Automattic and created a static IP, created an SSH tunnel and installed SSL using the bitnami tool `sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool` and the SSL installed successfully on my main domain name.

But whenever I access **phpMyAdmin** page on my machine using the SSH tunnel, the page lacks the SSL/HTTPS, how do I make sure the **phpMyAdmin page** is secured on my computer so I don't have to worry about hackers and stuff?

I have not tried anything so far because I don't know where to start.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi there! If you are already using an SSH tunnel, why do you need to install a TLS certificate? The traffic between your VM and you is already travelling using SSH secure connection so there is no way that somebody can steal your data. [1]

[1] https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/get-started/access-phpmyadmin/

Comment: @Taiwo D. Dare - Is existing issue resolved with help of above shared document

Comment: I thought if my browser doesn't have that padlock symbol, it's not secured. I've read a bit up about SSH, now I understand.  I'm still very new to this, so thank you so much.